# Extract first node value from JSON response using Groovy

Tags: json, groovy, soapui

I am trying to fetch the first node value (ResourceItemID i.e 2290) from my JSON response.
My Response is look like :

```
    {
   "Success": true,
   "TotalRecords": 41,
   "RoomSearchResult":    [
            {
         "ResourceItemID": 2290,
         "Name": "Room 23 (L02)",
         "LocationId": 7,
         "GroupID": 518,
         "FloorID": 2,
         "DefaultCapacity": 4,
         "CanBeBooked": true
      },
{
         "ResourceItemID": 2063,
         "Name": "Room 15 (L10)",
         "LocationId": 7,
         "GroupID": 518,
         "FloorID": 10,
         "DefaultCapacity": 8,
         "CanBeBooked": true
      }
   ],
   "Error":    {
      "ErrorCode": 0,
      "ErrorDescription": ""
   }
}
```

What i tried so far :

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def parsed = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json).find().value.RoomSearchResult.ResourceItemID
```

Comment: Do you need to extract `ResourceItemID` when condition is matched.

Comment: No, ResourceItemID can be anything. I just need to find and store first value into soapui property.

Comment: Ok, but there are list of values. Is it that `2290` a fixed value that you are looking for?

Comment: No, This value changes depends on my request. I just need to find first value whatever it is. OR may be sometimes need a second/third/Fourth... value.

Comment: Ok. Then how do you decide which value to pick from the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want only the first node value then you don't need to traverse the whole `JSON` manually, you can just parse it to collection and get the first node from it.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper


String jsonString = """
  {
   "Success": true,
   "TotalRecords": 41,
   "RoomSearchResult":    [
            {
         "ResourceItemID": 2290,
         "Name": "Room 23 (L02)",
         "LocationId": 7,
         "GroupID": 518,
         "FloorID": 2,
         "DefaultCapacity": 4,
         "CanBeBooked": true
      },
      {
         "ResourceItemID": 2063,
         "Name": "Room 15 (L10)",
         "LocationId": 7,
         "GroupID": 518,
         "FloorID": 10,
         "DefaultCapacity": 8,
         "CanBeBooked": true
      }
   ],
   "Error":    {
      "ErrorCode": 0,
      "ErrorDescription": ""
   }
}
"""

JsonSlurper jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()

/**
* 'jsonString' is the input json you have shown
* parse it and store it in collection
*/
Map convertedJSONMap  = jsonSlurper.parseText(jsonString)

//If you have the nodes then fetch the first one only
if(convertedJSONMap."RoomSearchResult"){

    println "ResourceItemID : " + convertedJSONMap."RoomSearchResult"[0]."ResourceItemID"
}
```

Output:

```
ResourceItemID : 2290
```

Comment: Error :- No such property: jsonString for class: Script7

Comment: Please have a look at updated answer. Input string is now declared above for better clarity.

Comment: Thanks Prakash, But my response is not always static. It keeps on changing according to my request. Is this possible to pass dynamic response in 'jsonString'.

Comment: Yes. I have taken it static for just showing the working example. You can use your dynamic json as input to JSON Slurper.
But your json will always contain `RoomSearchResult` right ?

Comment: Then above solution will work for you. If it works as you expect, please accept and upvote the answer so that others will also get it.

Comment: This is working fine for static. Can you please help me, how to pass dynamic json response to 'jsonString'?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146433/discussion-between-prakash-thete-and-raj).

Comment: Just put the above code in one function and pass your response as parameter to it and return the fetched `ResourceItemID` from it.

Comment: This Works. String jsonString = context.expand('${SearchRooms#Response}')

Answer (score 0):

You first need to navigate the nodes to get to the specific node type you want to extract the value from, not value first. Navigating down to the `ResourceItemID`and then getting the `value` will return an array of the values of all `ResourceItemID`s: `[2290,2063]`.
You can either get the first item of the array or find based on the value itself. 
The code below will print the example results:

`[2290, 2063]
2290
2290`

```
def parsed = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json).RoomSearchResult.ResourceItemID.value
println parsed
def result = parsed.find{ value -> value == 2290}
println result
result = parsed[0]
println result
```